# checking if variables are empty otherwise get the value

Tags: android

I want to get value from several variables for example user1, user2, user3, user4.
how to check if variables are empty otherwise get the value and ignore variables that empty.

how I achieve this?, and sorry for newbie question...

if I do this

```
if(user1 != null && user2!= null && user3 != null && user4 != null){
    user1.getText();   // or v1 = user1.value();
    user2.getText();   // or v2 = user2.value();
    user3.getText();   // or v3 = user3.value();
    user4.getText();   // or v4 = user4.value();
}
```

which I dont want to do that, I just want to get the variable which had value in it and save it in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code.

```
ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();

if(user1!=null)
{
  listItems.add(user1.getText());
}
if(user2!=null)
{
  listItems.add(user2.getText());
}

if(user3!=null)
{
  listItems.add(user3.getText());
}

if(user4!=null)
{
  listItems.add(user4.getText());
}

String [] arrayData = listItems.toArray(new String[listItems.size()]);
```

Note:You can also use **isEmpty()** method instead of checking for not a null value.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a null check?

```
Value v1;
Value v2;
if (user1 != null) {
    v1 = user1.value();
}
if (user2 != null) {
    v2 = user2.value();
}
...etc
```

Comment: and if I want to save it in array? I just don't want to storing empty value in array

Comment: I would suggest a list since you don't know how many items you will need to  add.  Just make a new List<String> items = new Arraylist<String>(); and each each non-null value to it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with **String** values then you may want to check the empty or null using [TextUtils.isEmpty(str)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) API

> **public static boolean isEmpty (CharSequence str)**
>   Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.

```
if(user1!=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(user1.getText()){
  //not empty or null
}
```